# Extracting specific elements of a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here's a list:

```
foo=[(1, 2, {'weight': 1}), (1, 3, {'weight': 2}), (1, 4, {'weight': 3}), (`1 5, {'weight': 4}), (1, 6, {'weight': 5}), (1, 7, {'weight': 6})]
```

Say I wanted to extract a particular element of each list within foo and store it in a separate list.

e.g. I wanted to extract 2nd element from each list, within foo and save it in the array labelled bar.

```
bar=[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

How can this be done in Python 2.7x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
bar = [i[1] for i in foo]
>>> print bar
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(1), foo))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```